# how to load image from local image path Ios Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, image, url

I have one **JSON** which contain **path of images** from one local folder of Project as Followed

[image]

The issue is i want to get image from that path, How do i achieve it?

I had try to convert **String to URL** and set URL as Image using **Kingfisher Library**

```
let url = URL(string: "/VWiOSProjects/CollageMakerDemo/Development/CollageMaker/CollageMaker/Goodies.xcassets/Goodies-1.imageset/Goodies-1.png")!

cell.imgTool.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

But it don't work I had Tried this one also

```
let url = URL(string: "/VWiOSProjects/CollageMakerDemo/Development/CollageMaker/CollageMaker/Goodies.xcassets/Goodies-1.imageset/Goodies-1.png")!

let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url)!
let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)

cell.imgTool.image = image
```

**NOTE: I can't upload this JSON file on Server, I need to use it Locally**

Comment: Basically the API `URL(string` is wrong. For paths in the local file system you have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath`, `URL(string` is only for URL string representations which include the scheme (`file://` or `http://`)

Comment: @vadian Thanks man! it works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved my issue using **fileURLWithPath**

```
let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/VWiOSProjects/CollageMakerDemo/Development/CollageMaker/CollageMaker/Goodies.xcassets/Goodies-1.imageset/Goodies-1.png")

let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url)!

let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)

cell.imgTool.image = image
```

Comment: Note that in Swift you don't need to include the actual `.init`. The preferred way is `URL(fileURLWithPath:`

Answer (score 3):

If the images are in Assets(`*.xcassets`) folder, the you can access it by `init(named:)` method.

```
cell.imgTool.image  = UIImage(named: "img1")
```

Actually you no need to store the entire path. You could store image names in array or something.

---

In my point of view, the best way is to add All Images to `*.xcassets` folder.(Because you have preloaded 5-10 images)

In case you needs to display it in collection view or TableView,

```
let imageName = "Goodies-\(indexPath.row)"
cell.imgTool.image  = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

Comment: I need to use it from JSON only

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it. Where you stored those images?

Comment: If i add Image in another folder of project then i can access it?

Comment: @LalKrishna, Thanks for you efforts, Check my post i have done what i exactly want

Answer (score 0):

If images are in assets folder itself then go for @Lal Krishna's method. And if they are on server then you should add http:// or https:// and the URL of server followed by JSON's URL.
If still you are not getting it then let me know.