# get Image from local path in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to get the UIImage from the local URL, but it doesn't work.
My `someURl`, where data is NSSecureCoding?: `file:///Users/a19468455/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2FA5B725-9266-429C-A036-256D846BC3FA/data/Media/PhotoData/OutgoingTemp/3F73D172-AA12-40AD-A3AB-540543A43330/IMG_0004.JPG`

Here's what I've tried (sacrificed code styling for convenience):

```
guard let inputItems = extensionContext?.inputItems as? [NSExtensionItem else { return }

inputItems.forEach { item in
            if let attachments = item.attachments,
               !attachments.isEmpty {
                attachments.forEach { attachment in
                    
                    if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {
                        var image: UIImage?
                        
                        attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil) { [weak self] data, error in
                            guard let self = self else { return }
                            guard error == nil else {
                                self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
                                return
                            }

                            if let someURl = data as? URL {
                                do {
                                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: someURl)
                                    image = UIImage(data: data)
                                } catch {
                                    print("failed to retrieve data")
                                }
                            }
                            if let image = image {
                                images.append(image)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I also tried tips from here without success:

[how to load image from local path ios swift (by path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574689/how-to-load-image-from-local-path-ios-swift-by-path)

[how to load image from local image path Ios Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928331/how-to-load-image-from-local-image-path-ios-swift-4)

[Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift)

I have no way to get Data from my link, how do I fix it?

Comment: So what is the type of `someURl`? This line (`if let someURl = data as? URL`) looks pretty suspicious.

Comment: What do you mean “data is NSSecureCoding“? First of all NSSecureCoding is a protocol and secondly how do you expect casting this to a URL could work?

Comment: Yes, I clarified the question